# How to implement ITokenHandle interface in UserService to revoke a reference token

Tags: access-token, logout, identityserver3

I have an Identity Server 3 based Authentication service. It's currently using JWTs, but I'm planning to switch over to reference tokens so that we can revoke them when the user logs out of the client application. I've been researching this ([Dominick Baier - Reference Tokens and Introspection](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/)) and understand that one option - the one I'd like to implement - is to have my user service - part of my authentication service implementation - use the Identity Server ITokenHandle interface to revoke the token. I have not been able to find any more information on this interface or how to implement it in my user service.

Has anyone done Identity Server 3 token revocation in their user service or can anyone point me to more information about this approach?

Comment: I don't know that I have an answer yet, but I found the posting I'd seen last year but wasn't able to find yesterday. That was this posting in GitHub: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1882 where someone was working on the same issue. That gets me to DefaultClientPermissionsService, different from ITokenHandler that I'd seen in the Dominick Baier post and for which I could find no additional info.

Comment: And I also find this post in GitHub: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2238, again someone doing the same thing I'm trying to do - revoke tokens through UserService when user signs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two GitHub postings in the comments on the original post contained the information I needed. I was able to switch from JWTs to reference tokens and then implement automatic revocation of the reference tokens on user sign out. The switch of the token type was a simple matter of setting

```
AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference
```

in my client setup code. To revoke the tokens on sign out I first added

```
idSrvFactory.Register(new Registration<DefaultClientPermissionsService>());
```

in Startup.cs. Then in my UserService, I added it to the UserService constructor

```
public UserService(DefaultClientPermissionsService clientPermissionsSvc)
{
    _clientPermissionsSvc = clientPermissionsSvc;
}
```

Then finally, still in my UserService, I implemented

```
public override Task SignOutAsync(SignOutContext context)
{
    string subjectId = GetSubjectId(context);
    _clientPermissionsSvc.RevokeClientPermissionsAsync(subjectId, context.ClientId);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```